# JavaScript to open in a new tab with location.href

Tags: javascript, window.open, window.location

I am building a custom linktree and Im struggling to find the right command to open these links in a new tab. Currently links are opened in current window as well as in a new tab.

```
let url = document.createElement('url');
    switch(event.target.innerText) {
      case 'youtube' : url = 'https://www.youtube.com/';break;
      case 'spotify' : url = 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/';break;
      case 'applemusic' : url = 'https://music.apple.com/';break;
      case 'soundcloud' : url = 'https://soundcloud.com/';break;
      case 'amazon' : url = 'https://media.giphy.com/';break;
      default: break;
    }
    if(url) {window.open(top.location.href = url, '_blank');}
```

When I replace **top** with **window** for the last line, like this:

```
if(url) {window.open(top.location.href = url, '_blank');}
```

it opens the url in a weird box inside my current window.

On a sidetone this is my first post, so please tell me in case I did something wrong.

Comment: `top.location.href = url` you're causing the page URL to change here, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is changing the URL of the current page - or the topmost ancestor if your page is inside a `<frame>` or `<iframe>` - to point to the specified URL, and then also opening a new tab/window for the specified URL.

Just use:

```
if (url) { window.open(url, '_blank'); }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that worked!